# What will be a circle look like considering this distance function?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis

I am working on some exercises in the book *Geometry: A Metric Approach with Models* by R.S. Millman. He defines the following map: $$d_S(P,Q):\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R\\\ d_S(P,Q)=\max\{~|x_2-x_1|,~|y_2-y_1|~\}$$ where in $P(x_1,y_1),~Q(x_2,y_2)$ are points in $\mathbb R^2$ and then wants the reader to show that $d_S$ is a distance function on $\mathbb R^2$.

I was thinking to myself of what would be a circle looked like regarding this function in Cartesian plane? I fixed a point, for example the origin, as a centre and then probed the case with a given positive constant $r$ as a radius. I just got two horizon $|y|=r$ or two vertical $|x|=r$ lines. the results didn't have good taste. Any help? Was I right? Thanks

Comment: I like the sentence: "the results didn't have good taste".

Comment: @Babak S.:Great question!+❶

Comment: Indeed, great question! +1

Comment: I hope you slept well!?

Comment: Wonderful! Start of a new, beautiful day...(and an end of my day)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. What you obtained is right. In general, the $p$-metric, where $p \geq 1$, is defined as
$$d_S(P,Q) = \left(\vert x_2 - x_1 \vert^p + \vert y_2 - y_1 \vert^p\right)^{1/p}$$
Now it is easy to prove that as $p \to \infty$, we get the metric $\max\{|x_2-x_1|,|y_2-y_1|\}$. Now you can use a plotting software and see how unit ball looks like for different $p$'s. You will find the for $p=1$, it is a diamond and as you increase $p$ you encompass "more" and "more" region in the plane. For $p=2$, you get the "usual" circle and for $p \to \infty$, you get the "unit square".

The diagram below shows the unit ball for different $p$'s. The inner most diamond is the case for $p=1$, which is also called as the taxi-cab metric. As $p$ increases, the "area" enclosed by the unit ball slowly increases. The outer unit square is the metric you get when you let $p \to \infty$, i.e., you get the metric $\max\{|x_2-x_1|,|y_2-y_1|\}$.

$\hskip0.5in$[image]

Comment: Will these open balls hold their shapes when we consider the Taxi-cab meter?

Comment: @BabakS. The Taxi-cab metric is the case when $p=1$. The unit ball corresponds to the inner most diamond in the figure, I have plotted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer as $p=1$.

Comment: For searching purposes: these curves are more commonly known as *Lamé curves* or *superellipses*.

Comment: The image is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We set

$$\max\{|x_2 - x_1|, |y_2 - y_1|\} = r$$

with $r > 0$ being a "radius".

Take a center for the "circle" -- say $(0, 0)$, to make this

$$\max\{|x|, |y|\} = r$$.

Now, this means at least one of $|x|$ and $|y|$ is $r$, and the other less. So there is a set of all $x$ for which $y = r$ and $|x| < r$, which is a horizontal line segment. For $y = -r$, we have another such segment, on the other side of the x-axis. Repeating for $x = r$ and $|y| < r$ and $x = -r$ and $|y| < r$, we get two vertical line segments. Altogether, we get a square with side lengths $2r$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the "circle" in this case, looks like a square.

Answer (score 3):

The correct result is squares. For simplicity, take a circle centered at $O=(0,0)$. For $P=(x,y)$, 
$$d_S(P,0)=\max\{|x|,|y|\}=r$$
if and only if $x=\pm r$ and $|y|\leq r$ or $y\pm r$ and $|x|\leq r$.

For a nice picture from *Mathematica*, I ran

```
center = {0, 0}; ContourPlot[ Max[Abs[x - center[[1]]], Abs[y - center[[2]]]], 
{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

which produces

[image]