# If $D=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|\leq 1-z^4\}$ then $D$ is a square with side $\sqrt{2}(1-z^4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $D=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|\leq 1-z^4\}$ then $D$ is a square with side $\sqrt{2}(1-z^4)$.

The absolute values can be interpreted as lengths with respect to their respective axes, but I still don't get it.
Please explain this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $z$ a fixed real number?

Comment: Yes $z$ is a fixed real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the line $x+y=a$ in the 1st quadrant ($x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$).  The line and the coordinate axes form a right triangle of side $a$, so the hypotenuse is of length $\sqrt{2} a$.

The region $D$ is formed by reflecting the hypotenuse about the $x$ and $y$ axes - note the absolute values provide fourfold symmetry.  This then forms a square of side length equal to a hypotenuse as above.

Answer (score 3):

For finding nice aspects of your inequalities have a look at [this](http://taxicabgeometry.net/general/definitions.html) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). I think the *Taxicab Metric* illustrating it, will show you the desired insight. Also you can see this very well designed [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/390128/8581) as well. I assume that $z$ is a fixed number here.

Comment: $\quad \ddot\smile \;\;+1$

Comment: @Babak Very nice referencing!